# Rest Assured - How to Validate Json response value based on value of previous Json node

Tags: json, rest-assured, assertion, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
In Rest Assured , I send a get request and below Json response is received.
```

//Json Response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Name": "REST",
      "Description": "Representational state transfer"
    },
    {
      "Name": "SOAP",
      "Description": "Simple Object Access Protocol"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to validate if name is REST then description is Representational state transfer , if name is SOAP then description is Simple Object Access Protocol. There are more than 20 records like the same in response and how can I do it through rest assured using generic parameters.

```
Also please advise how to parameter and do the assertion otherwise it will lead to more than 20 line of assertions alone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Done as follows

```
given()
    .when().get(url)
    .then()
      .root("data")
      .root("find { it.Name == 'REST' }")
          .body("Description", equalTo("Representational state transfer");
```

Hope you get the idea.